# Buying and insuring a car in the US for a roadtrip

Tags: usa, automobiles, rental, south-america

I'm a 19 year old UK resident, I'd like to buy a car in America and roadtrip for 6 months, would I be able to get insured on a van and for under $2000 ?

I'm travelling through America from California down through Mexico, through Central America down to South America and would like to know if it's possible to buy a car and insure it relatively cheaply at the age of 19.
cheers

Comment: That road trip is [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap).

Comment: 1. US insurers won't cover you outside the country.  2.  You most likely won't be able to register the car.  3.  What are you going to do with it once you reached your destination?

Comment: @Karlson expand on those and you might have an answer.

Comment: @CMaster Too broad to expand on those.  There are 48 states in the continental US with fairly broad regulatory base for insurances and car registrations.  I don't really care at the moment to research them all.

Comment: Define cheaply. With a car insurance you don't just insure YOUR $2000 bucket, but also the other guys new shiny sportscar you might crash into.

Comment: @gerrit unless you put the car on a boat from Panama to Colombia! Not sure how easy that'd be though. Probably complicated and expensive.

Comment: @Karlson the OP mentioned the intention to buy in California, which brings it down to one state. Possibly still too much work, but...

Answer (score 2):

1. $2000 is not enough to buy a van that you could rely on for a long trip.  Are you a mechanic?
2. Registering it might be a problem: you probably have to be a resident of the state. On the other hand, if the van has plates, you can just drive it on those plates and sell it to used-car place when you are done.
3. American insurance is only good in the US and Canada.  You would need to get special insurance in Mexico (they sell it at little shops along the border).
4. A lot of Mexico and Central America is... sketchy.  It is not particularly rare for a tourist to come home in a body-bag.  Or several separate body-bags.
5. As a Brit, you may not have a good sense of just how *big* North America is.  Land's End to John o' Groats is 1400 km.  The equivalent journey in the US would be from Marathon, Florida, to Anchor Point, Alaska, *8500 km*.  The US is *forty times* larger than the UK, so six months in the US is less than five days in Britain.  Canada is bigger still (although largely empty).

Comment: Point 4 is over dramatic and opinionated. Yes it can be dangerous, but I met many people who traveled in Mexico and Central America, they had a fantastic time. One thing is, it's probably not the type of place to go to if you have no previous travel experience.

Comment: @AdrienBe -- I recommend you _not_ Google "decapitation mexico".

Comment: have you ever traveled in Latin America yourself? I'm wondering if your opinion is based on experience as many times our prejudices (or what we think is knowledge) are proven wrong when actually trying things.

Comment: @AdrienBe, I have traveled only superficially in Mexico, but I can read the newspaper.  Maybe you should Google "decapitation mexico".

Comment: I think I have my answer :)

Comment: Let me also add that as a 19yr old with no US driving experience $2000 may not be enough to buy you insurance to drive in the US, let alone on a van and in different countries.

Comment: @Malvolio. So you have seen news stories, which, by their very nature describe unusal and exceptional cases. Do you have any statistics to suggest that relative to the number of tourists, being murdered is a "not particularly rare" occurance? I strongly suspect that the biggest threat to the life of the OP would be collisions on the road, an issue on which the US compares very poorly to his native UK as well.

Comment: Also a threat: car breaking down in a remote desert, followed by dehydration.